# Xamarin Android.Content.Res.Resources + NotFoundException

Tags: c#, xamarin

An exception is thrown when building the xamarin project: Android.Content.Res.Resources + NotFoundException: 'Resource ID # 0x7f0b0054'

Comment: Please clarify what is causing the problem and what you've done to try and resolve it

Comment: Is this a brand new xamarin solution? Is it Xamarin Forms or Xamarin Native? Do you have a link to the code so I can try to replicate the issue?

Comment: This exception is thrown by the resource APIs when a requested resource can not be found. Please check the resource exist or not. If you still cannot find it, could you provide the code which thrown the error for us?